In Safari, service worker doesn't intercept the first page load
I have created a very simple service worker as you see below. It simply intercepts the fetch requests and adds X-Custom-Header to the headers.
self.addEventListener('install', () => {
    self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
    event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.respondWith(fetchWithHeader(event.request));
});

function fetchWithHeader(request) {
    const newHeaders = new Headers();
    newHeaders.set('X-Custom-Header', `123`);

    return fetch(request, { headers: newHeaders });
}

I register the service worker for http://localhost:3000 like this:
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js', {
    scope: '/',
  });
}

In chrome and firefox, when I navigate to http://localhost:3000 (service worker is already installed), only one request is recevied by the back-end. But when I do the same in Safari, two requests are received by the back-end.
I investigated a bit and realised that in Safari, when I type http://localhost:3000 in the browser address bar, a request is sent before the service worker starts, then after the service worker starts, another request is sent which gets intercepted by the service worker.
I don't understand why Safari has this strange behaviour. Does anybody have an idea how to prevent this?
P.S: I tried with different versions of safari both on mac and iphone. Got the same results everytime.

I just ran into this issue too. It happens in Firefox and Safari, but Chrome works as expected. Did you ever figure this issue out?

Well more debugging...
  responsePromise async function
  event.waitUntil(responsePromise);
  event.respondWith(responsePromise);

before I was doing respondWith withion the async function directly. Doing that seemed to fix it. Idk why 100% but maybe it can help others who bump into this!
